# Days of Future Past: why did Magneto have to be broken out?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

In *Days of Future Past*, Wolverine's consciousness is sent to the 1970s to warn a young Professor X about the threat that the Sentinel program poses. In order to prevent the Sentinel program from being developed, they have to prevent the pivotal event that kickstarted it (Mystique's assassination of Dr. Trask) from taking place. But wait! Wolverine, Professor X, and Beast alone, badasses though they are, cannot pull this off alone. They need Magneto's help, and that involves breaking him out of a super-hyper-ultra-high-security jail. The daring extraction plan having succeeded, the heroes travel to Paris and manage to foil the assassination attempt at the last second.

Except that, when you look at it, Magneto didn't actually do anything up to this point. He went along for the ride, but the one who orchestrated everything (including telling Mystique not to pull the trigger) was Professor X. I can see the need for Magneto and Professor X reconciling, but this is something that could have been relegated as a not-so-urgent task, to be dealt with when Trask was discredited and the Sentinel program cancelled for good.

So, what exactly did Professor X need Magneto for at this point in the movie?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Influencing Raven's actions are an integral part of their plan to deprive the Sentinels of their shape-shifting abilities. Unfortunately she won't listen to Charles Xavier at that point in time, hence why they need Magneto.

During the [discussion between Wolverine and Charles](https://web.archive.org/web/20170312213358/https://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men:_Days_of_Future_Past) we learn that it's not enough for them to *prevent* the assassination, they want to stop it from happening entirely, depriving Trask and the US military of any opportunity to *see* Raven in action (and hence becoming aware of her powers) or getting hold of her blood.

> **Wolverine:** *We have to stop Raven. I need your help. We need your help.*
>
> ...
>
> **Charles:** *Let's just say for the sake of... the sake, that I choose to believe you... that I choose to help you. Raven won't listen
> to me. Her heart and soul belong to someone else now.*
>
> **Wolverine:** *I know. That's why we're gonna need Magneto, too.*

At the end of the film, they get an added and unexpected bonus. After the world saw how dangerous the Sentinel programme is (and seeing a mutant defending the President with their life) they not only didn't deploy the Sentinels, but it seems that the new timeline is rather more advanced technologically.